# Does air resistance give a falling skydiver weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, drag, free-body-diagram, weight

An observer in free fall is weightless as he is accelerating at 9.8 m/s^2. However, when a skydiver jumps from a high plane, his acceleration gradually slows until becoming 0 m/s^2 at terminal velocity. My question is, does the constant speed of a skydiver at terminal velocity mean that the skydiver has weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it this way - If he carried a scale strapped to his back, and sitting on the scale was a 1 kg weight, at the instant after he jumps out of the airplane the scale will read 0, but when he reaches terminal velocity the scale will read 1 kg.

So, what exactly does it mean to say that he has weight?

Answer (score 0):

*My question is, does the constant speed of a skydiver at terminal velocity mean that the skydiver has weight?*

Yes, the sky diver traveling at constant speed will feel the same gravity force as someone suspended with a cord from the roof of a building.